# How to change laravel route links

Tags: php, laravel-4

Okay i got a link from following codes like :

www.mysite.com/public/myRoute?id=11223355

But, i want to change id section of my link. How can i do that ?

Route here:

```
Route::get('myRoute', array(
    'uses' => 'myController@myRoute',
    'as' => 'myRoute'
));
```

Controller here :

```
class myController extends BaseController{
   public function myRoute(){
      return View::make('pages.myPage');
   }
}
```

home.blade.php here :

```
{{ HTML::linkRoute('myRoute', 'myLink' , array('id' => '11223355'), array('class' => 'text text-center')) }}
```

Comment: You can use `URL::route(string routeName, mixed param)` where param is the ID, and then do `public function myRoute($id)` in your controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Route::get('myRoute/{id}', array(
    'uses' => 'myController@myRoute',
    'as' => 'myRoute'
));


class myController extends BaseController{
   public function myRoute($id){
      return View::make('pages.myPage');
   }
}

{{ HTML::linkRoute('myRoute', 'myLink' , array('11223355'), array('class' => 'text text-center')) }}
```

Comment: I'd use `URL::route()` instead.

Comment: I agree, although I prefer the wrapper `route()` or `link_to_route()` to make the whole anchor tag. `URL::route()` only generates the URL, not the whole anchor tag :)